# OS X unwanted shortcut: ⌘⌘ converted to ⌘C

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

As the title says, whenever I repeat the ⌘ key it triggers a copy command (just as if I pressed ⌘C). I can even see the "Edit" menu entry blinking when I do that. This happens system-wide.

I checked OS X's shortcuts under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, but there's nothing there. I also checked other apps, like BetterTouchTool, but it's not defined in any of them.

This started happening a couple of months ago and I'm going a bit crazy with this. Is there any way I can know which app is creating / assigning each shortcut? That could massively help narrowing it down.

Thank you!

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are often set per user account. Do other user accounts have similar issues? Have you tried to restore the keyboard shortcuts to their default settings? (System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts 'Restore Defaults')

Comment: There is only one user account, mine. I've tried setting the shortcuts to their default settings, yes, but to no avail. I think a 3rd-party app is causing this, although I can't for the life of me figure out which one.

Comment: You can create a new user... This might help debugging this problem.

Comment: do you have a program or extension that modifies your clipboard in some way?  perhaps that program has an internal means of setting a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get some luck if you download and install [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) - it builds a list of shortcuts for the current application, so you may be able to track it down by working through your apps with that.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion to anyone hitting the same problem, so I accepted it. Eventually I did a clean install for Yosemite and the problem went away though :)